# How to control the flow of jobs in YAML with conditions?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want Stage B to run only if Stage A is successful ,
I want Stage C to run if Both A and B are successful

How can i achieve this will YAML?

stages:

- stage: StageA
  jobs:

  - job: DoStuffStageA
    steps:

stages:

- stage: StageB
  jobs:

  - job: DoStuffStageB
    steps:

stages:

- stage: StageC
  jobs:

  - job: DoStuffStageC
    steps:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the following YAML to check the status.

```
stages:
- stage: A

# stage B runs if A succeeds
- stage: B
  condition: succeeded()
    
# stage C runs if A and B succeeds
- stage: C
  dependsOn:
    - A
    - B
  condition: and(succeeded('A'),succeeded('B'))
```

For more information, you could refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml